# What is the difference between Singular Value Decomposition and Matrix Factorization for a Recommendation System?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, recommender-system

For collaborative Filtering method to recommend items to users, I have read articles on the Internet that we can do matrix factorization. However, I am confused about the term between Matrix Factorization and Singular Value Decomposition.

When reading things about Matrix Factorization, people seem to say create two matrices, generate random numbers for the two matrices, and then run gradient descent optimization algorithm to get the final numbers for the two factorized matrices.

But I have also watched videos on matrix factorization for recommendation systems using Singular Value Decomposition on Youtube. Are they the same things with doing different ways or are they different things?

Comment: SVD is a particular kind of matrix factorization, because it writes a matrix as the product of three matrices: $X = USV^\top$. The application to recommender systems might be the same or different, depending on whether "recommender system matrix factorization" has the same form and constraints as SVD. There are, in general, many kinds of matrix factorizations beyond those used in recommender systems. Elaboration on what factorizations you have in mind might allow a more detailed answer.

Comment: So in many recommender systems, you have a notion of missing data ( unrated films), so iterative approaches can  minimise error in rated films only  as opposed to SVD. See SVD++ matrix factorisation algorithm

Comment: @seanv507 Can you provde some links to SVD++ if know some? Anyway I will take a look at it. Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_factorization_(recommender_systems)